# How to fetch data from mysql and display in joomla article

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have already created a form in joomla article by using chronoform. When i fill in the form, the data will be saved in the database. But,I have some problem to fetch the data from database and display it in joomla article.

I created the form for the admin to edit the information when the admin log in to the website and display the information for the visitor. Only admin can edit the information. Other person who does not have access to log in the website only can view the information. Can someone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fetch the data refer this

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219876/how-to-get-article-text-by-article-id-in-joomla
```

You can give the permission for any user can access

```
Goto backend -> Chronoform -> Options -> Permission -> Public -> Here you can set.
```

Comment: Where is Goto backend?

Comment: Joomla administrator

Comment: Please don't provide links to deprecated code. The question is regarding Joomla 3.x, not 2.5